# SELECT INTO ##temptable from dynamic @sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql, temp-tables

SQL Server 2012.

There is a table with sql statements, maintained by developers.

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , sql_statement NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
  , recipient NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO t
SELECT 'select 1 as one, 2 as two, 3 as three'
     , 'some-email-address@host.com'
```

Every now and then, an automated process kicks-in and executes one of the statements, checks if it returned any rows and if it did, emails them. Important bit is, the process adds some extras to the email depending on various conditions so it is not a simple "generate and email csv data" task (we can't simply use the built-in feature of attaching query results to the email).

The process is supposed to be as dynamic as possible. In particular, it should support any valid SQL statements that return rows.

The current implementation to retrieve and process data from the sql_statement column is something like:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = sql_statement
  FROM dbo.t
 WHERE id = 1;

DECLARE @actual_sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * INTO ##t from (' + @sql + N') t;';
EXECUTE(@actual_sql)
DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @msg = 'plenty of heavy-lifting here, building the email message body based on the contents of ##t and various conditions'

DROP TABLE ##t

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @recipients = @recipients
  , ...                                    ...
  , @body = @msg
```

The issue with the above solution is that it prevents developers from using `WITH` statements in the `sql_statement` column, as they cause syntax error on the `EXECUTE(@actual_sql)` line (for obvious reasons: you can't `select from (with...)`). They can use subqueries in the `FROM` block but I want them to be able to use any SQL code that returns rows.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Are you *really* storing sql statements for execution in a table? That seems like a really bad idea; especially if you aren't ensuring that are completely "sanitised".

Comment: This is a valid concern. The statements are currently maintained by a narrow (<5 people) group of trusted people. There is no external access. I agree there is still risk (like someone adding a DROP DATABASE statement by mistake) and this has already been raised internally. For now, let's focus on answering my question i.e. how to support CTEs.

Comment: If you're forcing the format of the query to be `N'...FROM (' + @sql + N')'` you can't. A CTE has to be declared at the start of a statement, not the middle or end, but the `SELECT` for that CTE *does* need to be at the end. You'll have to force your users to use subqueries or change your solution (I suggest the latter, based on my prior comment).

Comment: One of my ideas was to inject " INTO ##t " clause just before the last "FROM" in the @sql variable but for many scenarios that wouldn't work (there could be subqueries at the end of the query using FROM keyword). Another one was to educate developers to always include " INTO ##t " in their queries but as the solution grows, I need to be able to run these things in parallel and generate ##t table name on the fly to avoid overlaps.

Comment: Focusing on your question would be doing you a disservice because this is an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @SeanLange You may be right actually. The bigger picture is, the sql statements return rows affected by various, pre-defined quality issues. Like, incorrect string lengths, date formats, missing values, values not in dictionary, values  failing certain parity checks and so on, the list is long. I want a general solution to detect those and notify interested / responsible parties. If my question is the Y, what would be your X then?

Comment: The best solution would be further back in the process. Why do you have sql queries returning errors? Handle bad data at the time it enters the system.

Comment: Data enters the system via a bunch of SSIS flows. There are literally hundreds of these flows, and they are creating verbatim copies of input files in the staging layer of an EDW, using truncate - load approach. If I wanted to implement quality checks in SSIS, I would need to modify *really* large number of packages and the whole thing would become unmaintainable really quickly. Staging area feeds the rest of the EDW so it is a viable candidate to perform any checks - in a centralized fashion - before errors propagate to higher layers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can manage to maintain a script that creates resultset schema for each sql_statement, this will work.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1
DECLARE @pre_sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '

        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1] (
            [one]   [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL
           ,[two]   [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL
           ,[three] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL
        )'
EXEC sp_executesql @pre_sql

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'with CTE AS(select 1 as one, 2 as two, 3 as three) SELECT * from CTE'

INSERT
    INTO t1 EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SELECT * FROM t1
```

Comment: That would work ok and I may go that way if there is no better option. It would double the number of scripts to maintain though (a select statement + a create table statement for each check). My initial idea was to write sql queries as <code>SELECT ... INTO ##t ...</code> which would solve the issue immediately for a single item. But then I realised people would be running checks in parallel and things would start breaking terribly. So I dropped the idea of global temp tables and am now trying to make it work without them.